# How can i fix Ruby on rails app on heroku which can't Login and redirect to homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, authentication

I recently installed [Catarse](https://github.com/catarse/) a Ruby on rails based app on [Heroku](https://heroku.com) which can be accessed here [App Link](https://pure-depths-2749.herokuapp.com/en/)

I'm new to Heroku and ruby so any help I can get would be great. The problem I'm experiencing is after deploying the app I can't login. The username/email and password is entered then the login button is click I'm then redirected to the home page without any warning or error.

How can I determine why I'm not able to login into the app on heroku and redirected to the homepage?

The user was created with the following:

```
$ admin = User.new({
    name: 'my-admin-name',
    email: 'my-admin@email.com',
    password: 'my-admin-password',
    password_confirmation: 'my-admin-password'
})

$ admin.save
```

If I attempt to register using the same email on the registration page I will be prompted with "Email has already been taken" therefore the account exist. I just can't login

Here are my logs:

```
    \pure-depths-2749>heroku logs
2015-03-31T23:36:41.425513+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning. Error encountered while sa
ving cache bdca0af185630201ca4675edc62168d03c57e893/_webflow.scssc: can't dump a
nonymous class #<Class:0x007f9435a6e2a0>
2015-03-31T23:36:41.425538+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-03-31T23:36:43.945059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=514M(100.5%)

2015-03-31T23:36:43.945059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded
)
2015-03-31T23:36:46.482422+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning. Error encountered while sa
ving cache bdca0af185630201ca4675edc62168d03c57e893/_main.scssc: can't dump anon
ymous class #<Class:0x007f9435a6e2a0>
2015-03-31T23:36:46.482428+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-03-31T23:36:46.976023+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning. Error encountered while sa
ving cache bdca0af185630201ca4675edc62168d03c57e893/_extra.sassc: can't dump ano
nymous class #<Class:0x007f9435a6e2a0>
2015-03-31T23:36:46.976029+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-03-31T23:36:47.213762+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/layout
s/_new_zendesk.html.slim (77.0ms)
2015-03-31T23:36:47.266743+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_facebook_sdk.ht
ml.slim (51.5ms)
2015-03-31T23:36:47.365160+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_crazzy_egg.html
.slim (43.9ms)
2015-03-31T23:36:47.475772+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_mixpanel.html.s
lim (29.5ms)
2015-03-31T23:36:47.300936+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/layout
s/_webfont.html.slim (33.1ms)
2015-03-31T23:36:47.476412+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 19361ms
(Views: 19167.3ms | ActiveRecord: 80.2ms)
2015-03-31T23:36:47.415963+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_analytics.html.
slim (49.3ms)
2015-03-31T23:36:47.491336+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=client at=error code=H18 d
esc="Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/en/password" host=pure-depths-2749.h
erokuapp.com request_id=3f99b7bd-3e6d-4c9b-a543-50a6869dfed7 fwd="140.216.561.79
" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20034ms status=503 bytes=887
2015-03-31T23:36:57.341447+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request
 timeout" method=GET path="/en/projects" host=pure-depths-2749.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=6d0ffcd9-851d-4735-b22e-893fe4df0d9f fwd="140.216.561.79" dyno=web.1 con
nect=0ms service=30004ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-03-31T23:36:59.165824+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2015-03-31T23:36:59.115504 #3]
ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:7 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
2015-03-31T23:36:59.435932+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2015-03-31T23:36:59.435793 #3]
ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 7 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
2015-03-31T23:37:04.077839+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-03-31T23:37:04.077503 #26]
  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2015-03-31T23:37:10.765051+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/en/" for 190.213.201.
61 at 2015-03-31 23:37:10 +0000
2015-03-31T23:37:18.274014+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProjectsController#in
dex as HTML
2015-03-31T23:37:18.274112+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
2015-03-31T23:37:19.356565+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_header.html.slim (53.2ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.356618+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_header_big.html.slim (382.3ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.402549+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/projec
ts/_card.html.slim (0.0ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.419278+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/projec
ts/_card.html.slim (0.0ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.556334+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_footer_about.html.slim (40.6ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.408945+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/projec
ts/_card.html.slim (0.0ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.623912+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_newsletter.html.slim (23.8ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.599052+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_footer_navigate.html.slim (41.8ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.514571+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_footer_welcome.html.slim (35.4ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.698225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/"
host=pure-depths-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=3e6d7f2f-bfcd-4738-bf54-415c48fbc
0c4 fwd="140.216.561.79" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9693ms status=200 bytes=
5293
2015-03-31T23:37:19.666087+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_facebook_like.h
tml.slim (40.8ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.683414+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_mixpanel.html.s
lim (0.1ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.682594+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_crazzy_egg.html
.slim (0.0ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.681929+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_facebook_sdk.ht
ml.slim (0.1ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.679554+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/layout
s/_new_zendesk.html.slim (0.2ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.667086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_footer_big.html.slim (223.6ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.683079+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_analytics.html.
slim (0.2ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.696467+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1410ms (Views:
1212.2ms | ActiveRecord: 27.8ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.667163+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/projec
ts/index.html.slim within layouts/catarse_bootstrap (1165.5ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:19.682164+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/layout
s/_webfont.html.slim (0.0ms)
2015-03-31T23:37:26.892033+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/catarse_bootst
rap/catarse-968ad7d0e8e4d26f16c27dc5a9825688.css" for 140.216.561.79 at 2015-03-
31 23:37:26 +0000
2015-03-31T23:37:28.706465+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][03/31/15 23:37:28 +00
00 web.1 (26)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/942472/app
lications/7592593
2015-03-31T23:37:33.275407+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/catarse_bootstrap/catarse-968ad7d0e8e4d26f16c27dc5a9825688.css" host=pure-dept
hs-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=b135f98f-45bd-4043-a82d-5349064802ca fwd="190.2
13.201.61" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12594ms status=200 bytes=19713
2015-03-31T23:37:33.726262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/logo-footer-00a039e0442e9aa77f91154e110532f8.png" host=pure-depths-2749.heroku
app.com request_id=76dca22c-e129-4e62-8db2-ac50ffc1518a fwd="140.216.561.79" dyn
o=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=3717
2015-03-31T23:37:33.719247+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/catarse_bootstrap/lupa-4c40ac88a951042d4320c89588a4d766.png" host=pure-depths-
2749.herokuapp.com request_id=0aa4c9b8-9231-4235-8526-645873e96e43 fwd="190.213.
201.61" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=1472
2015-03-31T23:37:33.724483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/catarse_bootstrap/loader-5d70369784c2cebed69affb92554cd6b.gif" host=pure-depth
s-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=81c7bd5c-b50c-48d6-a600-0ab2e8ec071c fwd="140.216.561.79" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=51305
2015-03-31T23:37:33.702919+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/catarse_bootstrap/icon-newsletter-3dbf29691958df54e9bf012f6e81553c.png" host=p
ure-depths-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=2a536b61-e5a4-4b24-8fb1-b658d5870bf6 fw
d="140.216.561.79" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=439
2015-03-31T23:37:33.706281+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/icon-blog-cbf858f1a5578442d48b02dd95e74516.png" host=pure-depths-2749.herokuap
p.com request_id=d058758d-fbbb-40bf-9059-4f24f2df738e fwd="140.216.561.79" dyno=
web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=3843
2015-03-31T23:37:34.035187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/catarse_bootstrap/logo_big-0513a67968a6c77bf3e5373c8e413ae3.png" host=pure-dep
ths-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=1a069451-f22a-4653-aff3-1ec402a30620 fwd="190.
213.201.61" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=338ms status=200 bytes=7300
2015-03-31T23:37:35.190677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/hero-home.jpg" host=pure-depths-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=c5fda42f-97f2-4e
a2-8c48-60c2cc637a7c fwd="140.216.561.79" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=16ms st
atus=200 bytes=93182
2015-03-31T23:37:35.190597+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/hero-home.jpg"
 for 140.216.561.79 at 2015-03-31 23:37:35 +0000
2015-04-01T00:07:32.238093+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/en/login" for 190.213
.201.61 at 2015-04-01 00:07:32 +0000
2015-04-01T00:07:32.248833+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
2015-04-01T00:07:32.248531+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsContr
oller#new as HTML
2015-04-01T00:07:32.677907+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/lo
gin" host=pure-depths-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=e83580da-ee52-4b25-a231-3cff
86251995 fwd="140.216.561.79" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=456ms status=200 by
tes=3406
2015-04-01T00:07:32.609568+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/devise
/shared/_header.html.slim (5.2ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:32.631029+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/devise
/sessions/new.html.slim within layouts/catarse_bootstrap (266.0ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:32.666289+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_facebook_sdk.ht
ml.slim (4.4ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:32.673751+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_crazzy_egg.html
.slim (2.7ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:32.683620+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_mixpanel.html.s
lim (3.9ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:32.660363+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/layout
s/_new_zendesk.html.slim (5.3ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:32.618198+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/devise
/shared/_alert.html.slim (5.9ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:32.669821+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/layout
s/_webfont.html.slim (2.6ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:32.684292+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 435ms (Views: 3
27.4ms | ActiveRecord: 14.9ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:32.678578+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_analytics.html.
slim (3.7ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:33.380677+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/asset
s/catarse_bootstrap/logo_icon_catarse-85692282dc7620548f2847e5e7e6e5cb.png" host
=pure-depths-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=de81be15-415b-4a9e-8aff-4b91d4297276
fwd="140.216.561.79" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1568
2015-04-01T00:07:39.951866+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/en/login" for 140.216.561.79 at 2015-04-01 00:07:39 +0000
2015-04-01T00:07:39.954445+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsContr
oller#create as HTML
2015-04-01T00:07:39.954483+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authen
ticity_token"=>"/rUsP9B9eYA1KuLG4XDl9tih99ux+B4zSPkeT4MhK/0=", "user"=>{"email"=
>"useremail@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit
"=>"Log me in", "locale"=>"en"}
2015-04-01T00:07:39.955196+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't verify CSRF token authenticit
y
2015-04-01T00:07:40.609247+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://pure-depths-2
749.herokuapp.com/en
2015-04-01T00:07:40.598647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/en/l
ogin" host=pure-depths-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=6659a072-2de9-4fdb-a78a-038
a07477473 fwd="140.216.561.79" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=666ms status=302 b
ytes=528
2015-04-01T00:07:40.609403+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 655ms (Activ
eRecord: 19.9ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:41.144458+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/en" for 190.213.201.6
1 at 2015-04-01 00:07:41 +0000
2015-04-01T00:07:41.854964+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/projec
ts/_card.html.slim (0.0ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:41.629591+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProjectsController#in
dex as HTML
2015-04-01T00:07:41.865902+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/projec
ts/_card.html.slim (0.0ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:41.629618+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
2015-04-01T00:07:41.824286+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_header.html.slim (41.7ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:41.824389+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_header_big.html.slim (70.6ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:41.860880+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/projec
ts/_card.html.slim (0.0ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.471706+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_footer_navigate.html.slim (1.3ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.529342+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_crazzy_egg.html
.slim (0.0ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.512371+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_facebook_like.h
tml.slim (0.2ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.446464+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_footer_welcome.html.slim (29.7ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.528566+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_facebook_sdk.ht
ml.slim (0.3ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.513779+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/projec
ts/index.html.slim within layouts/catarse_bootstrap (1762.5ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.544384+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_mixpanel.html.s
lim (1.1ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.527946+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/layout
s/_new_zendesk.html.slim (1.1ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.470271+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_footer_about.html.slim (23.3ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.510538+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_newsletter.html.slim (28.8ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.513489+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/shared
/_footer_big.html.slim (96.9ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.528854+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered catarse_bootstrap/layout
s/_webfont.html.slim (0.0ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.542880+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_analytics.html.
slim (1.1ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.544992+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1915ms (Views:
1787.5ms | ActiveRecord: 12.2ms)
2015-04-01T00:07:43.587039+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en" h
ost=pure-depths-2749.herokuapp.com request_id=5b147858-38f1-4bbe-8b5e-2523b2f899
a0 fwd="140.216.561.79" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=2611ms status=200 bytes=5
295
2015-04-01T00:07:52.789200+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded
)
2015-04-01T00:07:52.789160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=536M(104.8%)
```

Comment: Is this problem solved? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague, so this is going to be more of a story about how to proceed and directions to take, rather than a straight answer, which there isn't enough information for.

First off, you shouldn't be debugging on Heroku - i.e. in Production - unless you specifically need to, and if it needs to be debugged on Heroku, you should set up a staging environment separate from your production environment, at least once you have users. You need to set this app up to run on your local system, where it will be much easier and faster to debug, and won't disrupt any users of the app.

On local, you can run the app with `rails server`, and it will run in debug mode, which reloads the whole app on every request, so that you don't even have to restart the server to see your changes. You can also use a Ruby debugger, such as [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) or [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), to step through your code. It will also log much more detailed information to the standard output that you can use to help figure out what's going on.

Next up, on a quick inspection, it appears that app is using the [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem to manage logins. This is generally an excellent choice. When you use the Devise login and other related actions, it generally puts any text result in the [flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html). You will see this if you have a place set up in your view to display the flash. If you don't, then you should, and if you don't know what that is, then read up on it.

Next up, how did you create the user that you're trying to log in as? You should take a look at your database to see if your user actually exists. Check the models to see which model is configured as the user, and what devise modules it is using. Depending on how things are configured, devise may not allow you to login unless you have clicked a confirmation link that it might have tried to email to you when you created the account - if you don't have email configured properly, or if you created the user in the database manually, you might not even notice that this is a problem without a lot of hard debugging.